# Using PS: How to force delete files without sending to Recycle Bin?

Tags: powershell

I'm using below script in the task scheduler to delete some files every day:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\*.txt" -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {($_.LastwriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) ) -and (! $_.PSIsContainer)} | Remove-Item -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

It works. However, those files will be sent to Recycle Bin. So we still need to empty the Recycle Bin once a while. Is there a way to delete files with sending to Recycle Bin using PS script (or maybe some setting in windows)?

Thanks

Comment: This does not repro on my machine. What OS are you running and version of PowerShell?

Comment: You can configure the recycle bin to permanently delete items without retaining anything.  This setting is per-drive, however.

Comment: UnhandledExcepSean: weird, it is not sending to recycle bin now. not sure what changed. it will be great if can figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you didn't see files in the Recycle Bin that were manually deleted perhaps from testing?

Comment: The `Remove-Item` cmdlet does not delete to the recycle bin. Check if you have some kind of overload overriding the normal behavior (`Get-Command Remove-Item`).

Answer (score 5):

`remove-item` deletes the file without sending it to the recycle bin.